# Renaming the default 'admin' role in OrionJS/aldeed:roles

Tags: meteor, roles

As far as I know [OrionJS](http://orionjs.org/) uses [alanning:roles](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles) package for user Roles and the default role is called `admin` and I wonder if it's possible to rename it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Orion docs](http://docs.orionjs.org/v1.7/roles):

> Orion uses nicolaslopezj:roles for roles. Basically this package let us define actions and later assign allow/deny rules for that action.

Looking at that package, 'admin' is used as a string in several places of that package as a non-configurable default, and it doesn't look like you can configure it.

Comment: That seems to be the case, so there's nothing I can do besides forking the package and replacing all occurences of 'admin' string in it with 'something-else'?

Comment: Yeah correct, seems like that would be a pretty big undertaking though.